# how to combine multiple columns with similar names?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple columns with the same name mixed with other columns.
Some of these columns that I want to combine have null in the rows.
For instance,

```
  apple_0 apple_1
0     abc    None
1     abc     efg
2     hig    None
3     dsf    None
```

and I want:

```
    apple 
0     abc
1     abc, efg
2     hig
3     dsf
```

I have like 85 of these columns.
The actual names are: scheduleSettings_nodes_0_name, scheduleSettings_nodes_1_name and so on
How can I combine these?

Comment: Are the contents of the columns strings? Do you want the combined column to be a comma-separated string, or a list?

Comment: Yes, the contents are in strings and I'm trying to create a csv

Comment: Is this related to pandas?

Comment: yes, it is used in pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, you could also try using `agg` something like this.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'apple_0': ['abc', 'abc', 'hig', 'dsf'], 'apple_1': [None, 'efg', None, None]})


selected_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('apple')]
df['apple'] = df[selected_cols].agg(lambda x: ', '.join(map(str, filter(None, x))), axis=1)
```

Comment: I got an errorTypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Looks like you have mixed types in different columns. You could try mapping them to string. Edited my answer above, hope it helps.

Comment: It almost worked, but it's not combining the correct columns such as "scheduleSettings_nodes_0_name, scheduleSettings_nodes_1_name,scheduleSettings_nodes_2_name" and so on

Comment: Can you try changing the condition in `selected_cols` to match the correct columns. maybe `selected_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('scheduleSettings_nodes_')]`

Comment: Yeah I've tried but it's including other columns that start with same name but ends differently like "scheduleSettings_nodes_0_id"

Comment: Try doing a regex match

`import re`
`pattern = re.compile(r'^scheduleSettings_nodes_._name$')`
`selected_cols = [col for col in df.columns if pattern.match(col)]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246753/discussion-between-shivam-shakti-and-rebekah-lee).

Comment: Thank you! This is counting for single digit "scheduleSetting_nodes_._names" There are about 89 of these columns with the name so how can we also count those with double digits as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.apply` with `axis=1` to apply a function to each row. This function can use `str.join` to join the elements of all columns that match `apple_*` if the elements are not `NA`

```
def join_cols(row, sep, col_names):
    return sep.join(row[c] 
                    for c in col_names 
                    if not pd.isna(row[c]))

cols_to_combine = ["apple_0", "apple_1"]
df["apple"] = df.apply(join_cols, axis=1, args=(",", cols_to_combine))
df.drop(columns=cols_to_combine, inplace=True)
```

Which gives your desired output:

```
     apple
0      abc
1  abc,efg
2      hig
3      dsf
```

To figure out which columns match your pattern, you could do:

```
cols_to_combine = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith("apple_")]
```

There's probably a way to vectorize this, which would be preferred over `apply()` in terms of speed

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: using stacking to drop the null, then aggregation per group.

```
(df.filter(like='apple_')
   .replace('None', pd.NA)
   .stack()
   .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
   .reindex(df.index)
   .to_frame('apple')
 )
```

Option 2: using an internal loop with `agg`.

```
(df.filter(like='apple_')
   .replace('None', pd.NA)
   .agg(lambda r: ','.join(x for x in r if pd.notna(x)), axis=1)
   .to_frame('apple')
)
```

Output:

```
     apple
0      abc
1  abc,efg
2      hig
3      dsf
```

Comment: I got an error TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: Can you provide your input as DataFrame constructor? Do you have non strings in your dataset?

Comment: df=(df.filter(like='scheduleSettings_nodes_')
   .replace('None', pd.NA)
   .agg(lambda r: ','.join(x for x in r if pd.notna(x)), axis=1)
   .to_frame('NODES')
)

Comment: the column names are like: scheduleSetting_nodes_0_name, scheduleSetting_nodes_1_name and so on